# Query string works in the URL, but not work in http.get() delphi 7

Tags: delphi, indy

This is my query string:

---

```
http://statement.dana-insurance.com/api/insurance?input=<Statement><GroupId>aseman</GroupId><Password>As1234</Password><StatementNo>87841</StatementNo><StatementSerial>92/1/n</StatementSerial><StatementType>MINIBUS-SEDAN</StatementType><DriverSmartCard1>3146339</DriverSmartCard1><DriverSmartCard2>0</DriverSmartCard2><DriverSmartCard3>0</DriverSmartCard3> <NavySmartCard>1776166</NavySmartCard><TotalRentalPrice>320000</TotalRentalPrice><CityDistance>140</CityDistance><BodyInsurancePrice>0</BodyInsurancePrice><AboardInsurancePrice>1400</AboardInsurancePrice><OriginCode>31380000</OriginCode><DestinationCode>31310000</DestinationCode><MoveDate>1394/10/09</MoveDate> <MoveTime>18:31</MoveTime><PassengerCount>4</PassengerCount><ChairCount>4</ChairCount><NavyType>SEDAN</NavyType><CompanyCode>31523</CompanyCode><PlaqueNumber>575n19</PlaqueNumber><PlaqueSerial>12</PlaqueSerial><ValidateTime>1</ValidateTime><IsTtwicePaid>0</IsTtwicePaid><CarType>NORMAL</CarType><Type>INSERT</Type></Statement>
```

---

It works in the browser, but it does not work in `http.get()` in delphi 7, the error is:

```
server error http/1.1 400 bad request ( the date is invalid )
```

**Note: When I change my `ISP` and connect to another internet connection it works fine.**

**this is my code :**

```
http:=TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
HTTP.AllowCookies:=true;
http.HandleRedirects := true;
http.ReadTimeout := 45000;
param:=TStringList.create;
Strings := TStringList.Create;
http.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml';
http.Request.Accept := 'text/xml, */*';
http.ReadTimeout:= 100000;
Memo1.Lines.Add(Req_String);
try
dana_str:=http.get(Req_String);
```

......

Comment: thanks for edit. Caleb.

Comment: Show some code, please.

Comment: date is correct its persian(shamsi) date.

Comment: Try URL-encoding the URL, at least the part after `?`

Comment: when i use urlencode error is: server error ... path not found. `proxy setting` on `isp` is effected ? how check it.in some `isp` this work true but in some other not work.

Comment: Why are you passing such a long XML string in the **query string** to begin with and not in the **post body** instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must ensure that the URL you pass to `TIdHTTP` is properly encoded.  A web browser handles that for you automatically.  If you give your original URL to a browser and use a packet sniffer to look at how the URL gets encoded during transmission, you would see the actual URL is:

```html
http://statement.dana-insurance.com/api/insurance?input=<Statement><GroupId>aseman</GroupId><Password>As1234</Password><StatementNo>87841</StatementNo><StatementSerial>92/1/n</StatementSerial><StatementType>MINIBUS-SEDAN</StatementType><DriverSmartCard1>3146339</DriverSmartCard1><DriverSmartCard2>0</DriverSmartCard2><DriverSmartCard3>0</DriverSmartCard3>%20<NavySmartCard>1776166</NavySmartCard><TotalRentalPrice>320000</TotalRentalPrice><CityDistance>140</CityDistance><BodyInsurancePrice>0</BodyInsurancePrice><AboardInsurancePrice>1400</AboardInsurancePrice><OriginCode>31380000</OriginCode><DestinationCode>31310000</DestinationCode><MoveDate>1394/10/09</MoveDate>%20<MoveTime>18:31</MoveTime><PassengerCount>4</PassengerCount><ChairCount>4</ChairCount><NavyType>SEDAN</NavyType><CompanyCode>31523</CompanyCode><PlaqueNumber>575n19</PlaqueNumber><PlaqueSerial>12</PlaqueSerial><ValidateTime>1</ValidateTime><IsTtwicePaid>0</IsTtwicePaid><CarType>NORMAL</CarType><Type>INSERT</Type></Statement>
```

Note that there are two whitespace characters that have been encoded as `%20` instead.  URLs are not allowed to contain unencoded whitespace.

In `TIdHTTP`, you have to encode your original URL manually:

```pascal
dana_str := http.get(TIdURI.URLEncode(Req_String));
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
dana_base_url := 'http://statement.dana-insurance.com/api/insurance?';
data_query = 'input=...';
dana_str := http.get(dana_base_url + TIdURI.ParamsEncode(data_query));
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
with TIdURI.Create do
try
  Protocol := 'http';
  Host := 'statement.dana-insurance.com';
  Path := '/api/insurance';
  Params := ParamsEncode('input=...');
  dana_str := http.get(URI);
finally
  Free;
end;
```

Comment: thanks Remy Lebeau.  **two withespace**  was error . URLs are not allowed to contain unencoded whitespace.thanks alot .my problem solvd.